# Layout Qualifiers in Open GLES 3.0

Tags: graphics, opengl-es, glsl, opengl-es-2.0, swift-playground

I'm experimenting with using the Open GLES 3.0 API (with the accompanying core 330 GLSL shader language) in a Swift Playground.  I have the following declaration at the top of my vertex shader:

`layout(location = 0) in vec4 a_Position;`

My understanding of the layout qualifier is that is specifies where `a_Position` is in the Vertex Buffer Object's attribute indices.  (loose as my understanding of VAO's is..).

But my triangle doesn't render unless I also include the following code:

```
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0)
glVertexAttribPointer(
        0,
        3,
        GLenum(GL_FLOAT),
        GLboolean(GL_FALSE),
        GLsizei(MemoryLayout<Vertex>.size),
        BUFFER_OFFSET(0))
```

But my understanding of the layout qualifier would suggest to me that this is not necessary as the it is already specifying where `a_Position` lies in the vertex attribute array. (at index 0).

So either I'm missing some minor detail, or my understanding of how VAO data is accessed in shaders on the GPU is flawed.  It is probably both.  So why isn't the shader declaration with the layout qualifier sufficient to get my vertex positions into `a_Position`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`layout(location=0)` means that you don't have to call `glGetVertexAttribLocation` to get the attribute index for `glEnableVertexAttribArray` and `glVertexAttribPointer` calls. Those calls are still necessary.

Shader declaration is not sufficient because you still need to provide the information that is in the parameters of `glVertexAttribPointer`, like normalisation, data type etc.

Comment: so you still ned the enable call?  (not sure what this is enabling..) and you need to put in the `glVertexAttribPointer` param info because how else does the shader variable know about size/stride/type info right?  i was wondering how simply specifying an index in the layout qualify could be sufficient info..  but basically if you say `layout(location = 1)` you can reliably enable index 1 and set the attribPointer info for index 1 as well?

Comment: @AlexBollbach If an attribute is not enabled (`glEnableVertexAttribArray`) it will not be used during rendering. Yes, `layout(location=1)` means that you can reliably set the index to 1 in `glVertexAttribPointer`.